# Call function with arguments from a sequence?

Tags: xquery

Is there a generic way to call an xquery function with arguments obtained from a sequence?

For example, I can do this:

```
let $dateandtime := (xs:date('2006-08-15'),xs:time('12:30:45-05:00'))
return fn:dateTime($dateandtime[1], $dateandtime[2])
```

But is there a way to call `fn:dateTime` *without* explicitly specifying all the arguments and *just* supplying the sequence? (I realize this has limited utility because sequences cannot nest.)

Here are examples of how I would accomplish this in other languages:

- python: `functionname(*args)`
- javascript: `functionname.apply(null, args)`
- php: `call_user_func_array('functionname', $args)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, there is no way to do this in XQuery. Similar to other typed languages, such as Java, the assignment of function signatures will usually happen at compile time. As the number of items in a sequence may be unknown before evaluating the query, the static choice of the correct *function signature* would fail in many cases (a general note: a function may have several function signatures, and each signature may contain a different number of arguments).

However, Java offers the reflection package to dynamically access and call functions at runtime. The new higher order features of XQuery 3.0 could be used to introduce another `apply($f as function(*), $s as item()*)` function. If you believe that would be helpful, the [W3 Issue Tracker](https://www.w3.org/Bugs/Public/) could be the best platform to request such a functionality.

Comment: It's not clear how function signature lookups would interact with dynamic function calls. Good point.